# Formula to calculate adjusted close price like yahoofinance in python

Tags: python, math, yahoo-finance, yfinance

So, I have been trying to create a manual function in python that calculates the adjusted closing price of stocks using dividends and stock splits data but I couldn't get results similar to yahoo finance

Can someone please help ?

Thanks

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYogz.jpg)

```
            open       close   adj close    volume  dividends  stock splits
47    127.666664  127.766663   99.105476  13274857   1.100000           0.0
293   158.533340  159.833328  126.355896   4965291   3.000000           0.0
532   234.333328  226.600006  181.832520  11126308   3.500000           0.0
780   222.199997  222.266663  181.591782  10778008   4.000000           0.0
1023  209.199997  202.933334  169.113434  20673919   4.166667           0.0
1266  235.600006  237.666672  199.166885   7362553   1.333333           0.0
1517  315.000000  317.450012  270.044617   9482413   4.750000           0.0
1759  272.399994  272.299988  236.060104   9244273   5.150000           0.0
2000  302.149994  299.750000  264.834930  13737694   5.750000           0.0
2275  200.350006  199.800003  185.603943  34710176  10.150000           0.0
2436  212.000000  207.050003  196.897675  51546288   5.000000           0.0
2508  208.699997  209.300003  204.572861  30719587   5.750000           0.0
2678  226.000000  219.449997  219.449997  22745228   5.250000           0.0
            open       close  adj close    volume  dividends  stock splits
1290  243.300003  252.350006  211.47168  27944232        0.0           1.5
```

So, The zero column is the index, What I did here is I selected all the indexes in df having dividends and stock splits

The 1,2 columns show the stock open and close price data, 5 and 6 column shows the dividends and stock splits data of the company

So, using 1,2,5, and 6 columns I want to calculate the adjusted closing price, which should be exactly or very similar to 3 column "adj close" price.

Basically, What I want to figure out is

"adj close" = Some_Mathematical_Formula_Using("open", "close", "dividends", "stock splits")

If the formula answer matches with the given "adj close" column data then I'll be using the same formula for calculating "adj open"

Please use the below data to use the formula and above data to get total dividends and stock splits data

```
            open       close   adj close    volume  dividends  stock splits
1285  235.033340  236.066666  197.826096  12047383        0.0           0.0
1286  236.066666  239.300003  200.535645  10245025        0.0           0.0
1287  240.000000  245.666672  205.870972  15696559        0.0           0.0
1288  246.633331  244.199997  204.641907  11554816        0.0           0.0
1289  245.333328  245.600006  205.815109  20901951        0.0           0.0
1290  243.300003  252.350006  211.471680  27944232        0.0           1.5
```

Comment: Can you edit your two lines of code into the question as text, please?

Comment: I reformatted your data block, but can you explain what it means, and what you want to do with it?

Comment: Thanks for reformatting the data block

Comment: Did you do any web searching at all?  The first Google hit has their formula. https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28256.html

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I tried it but couldn't get the result similar to adj close

Comment: Since you have tried, can you show what you tried, and how your output is different from what you expect?

Comment: Index 1288: (1 - (41.8/245.600006)) * 244.199997 = 202.6382
But Actual value for adj close is 204.641907 from table

The above calculation is done from the above mentioned yahoo help link

Comment: @joanis any idea.. ?

Comment: I expect I could solve this, yes, but as I asked earlier, please show your own attempt at coding this, and we can help fix it.

Comment: By the way, it looks like the adjusted close figures you show don't take into account the 1.5 stock split at 1290. I would guess this data is wrong, perhaps the problem is not with your code.

Comment: Also, what's a 1.5 split? From that Yahoo link someone posted, it looks like splits are supposed to be 1 to some integer, or some integer to 1 for reverse splits. I don't know what 1.5 would mean.

Comment: @joanis thanks for replying. So, I don't think there's a problem with the data or neither the problem is in stock splits using 1.5, I scrolled through the data of yahoo finance and it shows the *Close price adjusted for splits